# Forums for Guitarists

Tags: learning

Which are some the largest and most popular Internet Forums for Guitarists?

Ideally a large community, with input regarding all aspects of learning to play, song suggestons and advice on popular techniques.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of information and resources at The Gear Page (http://www.thegearpage.net/board/).  I've been a member there for just over a year, and learned more about guitars in that time than my previous 25 years of playing in bands etc.

Comment: Been a member of TGP for 7 years. Great community.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to promote `http://guitars.stackexchange.com` on this forum to boost some activity here? Might eventually bring it past the beta stage...

Comment: Great idea - I'll start to do that on TGP.  Lot of experts on there whose knowledge would be useful here.

Comment: Well, I just noticed that Guitars SE is about to be merged into a new proposal for "Musical Practice and Performance". See `ANNOUNCEMENT — Save “Guitars SE” by Supporting the Music Proposal`. So maybe it would be better to wait, and promote that one instead, once it becomes public beta (which is 5 days from now).

Answer (score 3):

Ultimate guitar is not bad, though a little young/metal oriented.... If your fall into that demographic you'll be happy.
I like the Acoustic Guitar Forum:
http://www.acousticguitarforum.com/forums/index.php
Since I'm primarily an acoustic guy.

There are a number of specialist forums like the "flatpicker's hangout" and the "Fingerstyle guitar" community... These are slow but have some good information.

Answer (score 2):

the board of Ultimate Guitar sounds like your thing:
http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/

They have also loads of tabs on their site!

Answer (score 0):

The forums on Harmony Central are decent.  There are a few *really* knowledgeable people there that raise the bar pretty high.

With that in mind, some people hate it for reasons I can't fathom.

http://acapella.harmony-central.com/

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Ultimate Guitar no good ever comes from that forum unless you want your questions answered by 13 year old Metalheads who think that everyone should play LTD's.

Rig-Talk is brilliant it has moderators from some of the best boutique companies in the world, also check out Huge Racks inc too both of these forums attract professional musicians, luthiers, amp builders etc. which means you will get more informative answers to your queries.